# ApplePay JS Integration - Merchant validation

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, applepay-web

Hi I am implementing ApplePay using JS. I am on merchant Validation. Sesion is returning me the validation URL which is "https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession"

I am using this validation URL in POSTMAN with the parameters explained in the documentation

```
{
"merchantIdentifier": "merchant.com",
"displayName": "abc.com",
"initiative": "web",
"initiativeContext": "abc.com"

}
```

But in response I'm getting Socket hung up error. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Please let me know if any more details are required.